# Показ случайных фраз по клику

Tags: javascript

Код через заданное время показывает с низу статической фразы "**НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО**" рандомно фразы 'ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'.

Выглядит это так: 
Показывается фраза "**НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО**" под этой фразой отображается надпись "Ждите 5 секунд", через пять секунд пропадает надпись "Ждите 5 секунд" и отображается обратный отсчет, затем рандомно показывается одна из этих фраз: 'ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'

**Нужно чтобы скрипт запускался по клику, то-есть**:

- пользователь видит фразу "НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО"
- под низом фразу "КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ"
- при клике на фразу "КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ" пропадает фраза "КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ" и отображается надпись "Ждите 5 секунд", через пять секунд пропадает надпись "Ждите 5 секунд" и отображается обратный отсчет, затем рандомно показывается одна из этих фраз: 'ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'

Заранее благодарен.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let easyTimer = (function(words, timer, greetings, element) {
    render = val => element.innerText = val ? val : timer === 0 ? words[parseInt(Math.random() * words.length)] : timer
    render(`Ждите ${timer} секунд`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeout(() => element.classList.remove('red'), 1000)
      let interval = setInterval(() => timer-- && render() && 0 === timer && clearInterval(interval), 1000)
    }, greetings * 1000)
  })(
    ['ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'],
    65,
    5, // сколько секунд показывать "Ждите секунд"
    document.querySelector('.rnd-word')
  )
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО</div>
  <div class="rnd-word red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: все работает, не так ли?

Comment: @michael_bestПростите. Что работает!? Задача не решена.

Comment: @michael_bestЯ редактировал. Внес ясность в описание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вон новая реализация, когда при повторном клике процес не запускается.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let easyTimer = (function(words, timer, greetings, element) {
    let render = val => element.innerText = val ? val : timer === 0 ? words[parseInt(Math.random() * words.length)] : timer;
    
    element.classList.add("red");
    render(`Ждите ${greetings} секунд`);
    let greetingsTemp = 3; // указание сколько секунд показать фразу "Ждите __ секунд"
    let timerWait = setInterval( () => {
        greetingsTemp > 0 ? greetingsTemp-- : countDown();
      }, 1000);

    let countDown = () => {
      clearInterval(timerWait);
      element.classList.remove('red');
      render();
      let interval = setInterval(() => timer-- && render() && 0 === timer && clearInterval(interval), 1000);
    };      
  });

  const listener = function(){
    document.querySelector('.rnd-word').removeEventListener("click", listener);
    easyTimer(
      ['ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'],
      12,
      5, // сколько секунд показывать "Ждите секунд"
      document.querySelector('.rnd-word')
    );
  };
  
  document.querySelector('.rnd-word').addEventListener("click", listener);

})
```

```css
.red {
   color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО</div>
  <div class="rnd-word">КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ</div>
</div>
```

Как замечание не пишите код в таком стиле. Старайтесь без необходимости не использовать стрелочные функции.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПаПрисутствует небольшой баг. При нажатии на цифры обратного отсчета, таймер возвращается в исходное, и отсчитывает по новому. Возможно-ли решить этот момент?

Comment: Действительно, не пришло в голову проверить, этот факт даже немного упрощает реализацию. Код я поправил.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПаВыявился серьезный глюк. А именно: обратный отсчет и информационная цифра "Ждите секунд", теперь взаимосвязано работают. То-есть если нужно чтобы отсчет был 80 сек., то соответственно нужно в коде установить для "Ждите секунд" также 80, в итоге идет показ 80 сек., фразы "Ждите секунд" и еще сам отсчет 80 сек. Требуется чтобы фраза "Ждите секунд" работала автономно.

Comment: поправил реализацию, извините что так долго - отпуск. Дополнительно добавил анимацию "ждите __ секунд" (если это не нужно легко можна убрать). Указанный вами глюк о взаимосвязи - исправлен.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПаВсе не так. Между слов "Ждите секунд" не должен идти отсчет, здесь должно отображаться число таймера, сколько нужно ждать. При нажатии на фразу "КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ", должна показаться фраза "Ждите 80 секунд", а сколько фраза "Ждите 80 секунд" будет отображаться задает администратор в коде, 5 или 2 секунды.

Comment: Еще раз поправил код.  Фраза "Ждите __ секунд"  будет показыватся количество секунд которые вы зададите в коде, я отметил то место коментарием. Хотя логичнее такое  время передавать дополнительным параметром.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос довольно сумбурный, хотя и подробный.

Я понял его так - добавить область по клику на которой запускается механизм обратного отсчета и генерация случайного результата. В оригинале запуск происходит сразу после создания таймера.

- поменял 65 секунд на 12 чтобы меньше "втыкать в экран";
- ждите 5 секунд - не анимировал, потому как это вроде не нужно.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let easyTimer = (function(words, timer, greetings, element) {
    render = val => element.innerText = val ? val : timer === 0 ? words[parseInt(Math.random() * words.length)] : timer;
    element.classList.add("red");
    render(`Ждите ${greetings} секунд`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeout(() => element.classList.remove('red'), 1000)
      let interval = setInterval(() => timer-- && render() && 0 === timer && clearInterval(interval), 1000)
    }, greetings * 1000)
  });
  document.querySelector('.rnd-word').addEventListener("click", () =>{
    easyTimer(
      ['ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'],
      12,
      5, // сколько секунд показывать "Ждите секунд"
      document.querySelector('.rnd-word')
    )
  });
  
})
```

```css
.red {
   color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО</div>
  <div class="rnd-word">КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийЯ редактировал. Внес ясность  --> при клике на фразу "КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ" пропадает фраза "КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ" и отображается надпись "Ждите 5 секунд", через пять секунд пропадает надпись "Ждите 5 секунд" и отображается обратный отсчет, затем рандомно показывается одна из этих фраз: 'ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'

Comment: Полезное уточнение, Я поробую переделать свой ответ для реализации этих требований.

Comment: Внес изменения. Надеюсь это то что нужно. При повторном клике процес опять будет запущен, если это не требуется - надо снять обработчик клика на .rnd-word после окончания работы последнего таймера.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПаЕсли вас не затруднит, можете показать код, как сделать, чтобы при повторном клике процесс опять НЕ запускался. Я в этом не понимаю.  Пожалуйста не удаляйте прежний код, создайте новый.

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось исправить код, я убрал не нужные setInterval();
(Все закоментировано)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.rnd-word').forEach((item) => { //Каждый элемент
    item.addEventListener('click', () => { //При нажати на него
      let easyTimer = (function(words, timer, element) { //Вызвать эту функцию
        element.classList.add('red'); //Сделать элемент красным
        render = val => element.innerText = val; // Добавить анонимную функцию render
        render(`Ждите ${timer} секунд`) // Вывести изначальное значение
        var int = setInterval(() => {
          element.classList.remove('red'); // Вернуть цвет обратно 
          timer--; // Отнять от таймера
          render(`Ждите ${timer} секунд`) // Вывести
          if(timer==0) // Если таймер закончился
          {
            clearInterval(int); //Отчистить интервал
            element.innerText = words[parseInt(Math.random()*3)]; // Вывести случайный элемент из массива
          }
        }, 1000)
      })(
        ['ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'],
        5, // сколько секунд показывать "Ждите секунд"
        item
      )
    });
  });
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО</div>
  <div class="rnd-word">КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ</div>
  <div class="rnd-word">КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ</div>
  <div class="rnd-word">КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ</div>
  <div class="rnd-word">КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ</div>
  <div class="rnd-word">КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ</div>
  <div class="rnd-word">КЛИКНИТЕ ЧТОБЫ СКОПИРОВАТЬ</div>
</div>
```